# Can anyone identify this connector on my laser cutter cable?

Tags: identification, connector

This is the cable to the laser on my laser cutter.  It's 2mm pitch.  I need to build a new cable and I've been looking and looking for what it is, but no luck.  If anyone knows, I'd really appreciate it.

EDIT

If I break out my loupe, I can see there is a very tiny "ZJT" embossed above the first position.

[image: Corner]
[image: Front]
[image: Back]
[image: Top]
[image: Socket]

Comment: It looks like JST but I searched JST and didn't see anything quite like it. Try Hirose. I don't think it's Molex either.

Comment: Look carefully for a logo or series number.  These often have them (need magnifying lens.)

Comment: If you don't care about the latch though, any latchless square 2mm female connector should fit into the board header.

Comment: @rdtsc - If I break out my loupe, I can see there is a very tiny "ZJT" embossed above the first position.

Comment: @DKNguyen - I may have to do that.  I'll need to anchor the cable securely by the socket for the drag chain anyway, so the friction of the socket and pins might be enough for it to stay put.

Comment: Could it be [CJT](https://www.cjt.com/en/ny.php?lm=81)?

Comment: @rdtsc - Alas, no.  The emboss on that is clear.  I think there might also be something above the 8 position, but it's so muddy I can't read it even at 10x magnification.

Comment: Or if you're building a new cable and scrapping this one, you could try pulling out a wire and looking at the crimp terminal and see if you can't find a similar looking crimp terminal and see if they fit into the housing. Then re-use the housing.